# Getting error as Column Id not Found while running SpringBoot Application?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am trying to get Image path based on photoId  but getting error as id not found

My entity class :

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="pid")
    private int pid;
    @Column(name="imagepath")
    private String imagepath;
    @Column(name="photoid")
    private int  photoid;
```

And Repository

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT c.imagepath FROM photos AS c WHERE c.photoid = :photoid", 
                   nativeQuery = true)
            List<PhotoModels> getImagePath(int photoid);
```

StackTrace:-

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        c.imagepath 
    FROM
        photos c 
    WHERE
        c.photoid = ?
2020-07-08 15:08:48.954  WARN 16424 --- [nio-8990-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2020-07-08 15:08:48.954 ERROR 16424 --- [nio-8990-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'pid' not found.
2020-07-08 15:08:48.956 ERROR 16424 --- [nio-8990-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT c.imagepath FROM photos c WHERE c.photoid = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'pid' not found.
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: stackTrace added please check

Comment: why is you getImagePath methode called on spring startup? is it coming from a spring batch or any other data processing, make sure your database schema is created before, your data processing

Comment: I had already database schema

Comment: The error message is clear. pid is not found. is it written PID? Are you running mysql on Windows?

Comment: yes i m using the same

Answer (score 0):

**See the following.**

1. Please verify your import statement for @Id. Might be wrong import
2. Verify if you have a column present in your table.
3. Please correct your SQL query as JPA does not allow you to select specific column's in native queries and bind them directly to an entity. Either select all OR bind specific column's to a DTO object OR process the query result and then bind result into Entity object OR use JPQL new constructor approach to get specific column's from a native query which will be mapped directly into entity.